# Dual boot windows 8 and ubuntu more official way

Tags: dual-boot, windows, windows-8

I Know that there are more questions about dual booting windows and ubuntu. However mine is a little different.
I did my research but I did not find any solution at my problem at this group.

I have dual boot win and ubuntu using EasyBCD and it works just good.

With this practice, if I log in at ubuntu, and I shut my pc down, then the next time grub will load, instead of the official windows bootloader. In addition if I select windows from grup, windows take a long time to boot.

I'd like to know whether is anybetter way to make it. e.g. something official from microsoft that recognises ubuntu ( or even shows for example the ubuntu logo at the boot screen.)

Thank you guys

Comment: "something official from microsoft that recognises ubuntu" what are you asking here? Windows systems do not even acknowledge Linux and you expect some bootloader from Microsoft to support anotherOS?

Comment: and have a look at BURG if you want a more graphical boot ;)

Comment: You are currently chainloading GRUB from EBCD/Windows Bootloader. This is bad and slow. You should do it the other way around, which is default if you let Ubuntu setup your bootloader.

Comment: @Rinzwind Just asking :) I did not expect that something from microsoft exists, but I just ask:) Thank you guys

Answer (score 0):

I guess win tries to attach ext fs with no success at boot time hence you have the delay. Nothing you can do about that.